# Let $n\in\mathbb N$, and $A_n = \left\lbrace k\in\mathbb N : k < n \right\rbrace$. Then how to show: if $A_m\approx A_n$ then $A_m = A_n$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Let $n\in\mathbb N$, and $A_n = \left\lbrace k\in\mathbb N : k < n \right\rbrace$. The symbol "$\approx$" means that there exists a bijective function from one set to another set. Show that if $A_m\approx A_n$ then $A_m = A_n$.

Comment: Could you prove it by induction over $m$?

Comment: As you can see from our discussions below, we want to know what tools are available to you.  Is this in a rigorous set theory class?

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith Yes, I hope it is rigorous. I've known that this proposition can be proved easily by Schröder-Bernstein Theorem. So do not use Schröder-Bernstein Theorem. Mathematical induction can be used.

Comment: How do you prove it using the Schoder-Bernstein Theorem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We prove it by induction on $m$.  The case $m = 0$ is easy, because $A_0 = \emptyset$.  So if $n \ne 0$, then $A_n$ is non-empty, and there is no bijection between the empty set and a non-empty set.

Suppose the statement is true for $m$.  Let $f:A_{m+1} \to A_{n+1}$ be a bijection.  Suppose that $f(m) = v$, and $f(u) = n$.  (We know that $u$ and $v$ exist and are unique because $f$ is a bijection.)

Define $g:A_m \to A_n$ by
$$ g(x) = \cases{f(x) & if $x \ne u$ \\ v & if $x = u$.} $$
Then check that $g$ is a bijection.  Hence $m = n$, and so $m+1 = n+1$.

Comment: I supposed $A_{m+1}$ ≈ $A_{n}$ before, so I failed to prove it. Suppose $A_{m+1}$ ≈ $A_{n+1}$ may be the key to prove it by mathematical induction.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Use the pigeonhole principle to show that if $m>n$, there is no bijection from $A_m$ to $A_n$.

Comment: Isn't the pigeonhole principle what he is trying to prove?

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith: No way to tell without knowing what tools are already available to the OP. Questions like this one are almost always somewhat ambiguous, and experience says that we can’t even safely assume that the available tools are actually adequate.

Comment: He did tag it "elementary set theory."  Outside of set theory and logic, what he wants to prove is intuitively obvious.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith: $(1)$ Users’ use of tags is unreliable. $(2)$ ‘Elementary set theory’ as taught includes a lot of pseudo-rigorous approaches. It’s entirely possible that the approach that I suggested is not acceptable; it’s also entirely possible that it is acceptable.

Comment: But in any pseudo-rigorous approach to mathematics, this statement is obvious.  I remember seeing this statement proved when I was an undergraduate, and at the time, I remember thinking "what's the point?"  Only in a rigorous setting does one see the need to prove this kind of thing.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith: No. I have seen approaches that attempt rigor and ask students to prove (or even purport to prove) statements (like this one) that in most courses would be taken for granted but which simply cannot be proved rigorously with the tools actually made available. That’s why I always hesitate to answer this kind of question unless it’s really clear that the OP is taking a serious set theory course.